# Pandas read_excel for multiple sheets returns same nb_rows on every sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got an Excel file with multiple sheets with same structure. 
Number of rows varies on every sheet, but `pd.read_excel()` returns `df` with `nb_rows == nb_rows on the first sheet`.
I've checked Excel sheets with `CTRL+down` - there is no empty lines in the middle of the sheet.
How can I fix the problem?

The example code is follows:

```
import pandas as pd
xls_sheets = ['01', '02', '03']
fname = 'C:\\data\\data.xlsx'
xls = pd.ExcelFile(fname)
for sheet in xls_sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(io=xls, sheet_name=sheet)
    print(len(df))
```

Output:

```
>> 4043  #Actual nb_rows = 4043
>> 4043  #Actual nb_rows = 11015
>> 4043  #Actual nb_rows = 5622
```

python 3.5, pandas 0.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Check the names of sheets are they correct in your xls_sheets list if yes then Try it after installing xlrd library/module (pip install xlrd) and then run the code again. Because for me it works fine. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited information on the question and assuming you want to read all of the sheets in the Excel file, I would suggest that you use the following:

```
data=pd.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

`data`is a dictionary where the keys are the sheet names and the values are the data in each sheet. Please try this method. It may solve your problem.